# Python float range as dictionary index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to use numeric (Float) ranges as a dictionary index. Consider my following code:

```
def range_index(table, val):
    for (k1, k2) in table:
        if k1 < val < k2:
            return table[(k1, k2)]

TIERS = {
    (51, 100): 1,
    (21, 50): 2,
    (11, 20): 3,
    (6, 10): 6,
    (2, 5): 12,
    (0, 1): 24
}

print(range_index(TIERS, 2.00))
```

Produces: `None` but I expected it to produce: `12`. How to do range as index properly? I like this tuple approach but need him fix.

Comment: change to `if k1 <= val <= k2:` ? You are checking for exclusive edges so `2` is not in any range...

Comment: ah super obvious thx

Comment: I'd also probably make it `for (k1, k2), tier in table.items()` and then `return tier` from your `if`

Comment: In the spirit of improvements, right now you are searching the whole dict every time (`O(N)`) which kinda loses the point of a dict. A better idea might be simply "opening-up" the ranges to be multiple keys with the same value. And then it will just be like searching in a regular dict...

Comment: If someone wants to put these comments in the form of an answer, especially as performance is concerned, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: Can you define properly first what is the exclusion rule for the edges? Meaning, for key `(51, 100)` should `51` and `100` be accepted?

Comment: yes. should include edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the obvious fix will be to adjust the comparison of `val` properly:

```py
if k1 <= val < k2:
```

---

But beyond that, you are actually iterating through the dict's keys for each `val` - that's `O(N)` in the worst-case. This is exactly the opposite of the dictionaries' purpose. In order to really fulfill it, you can "flatten" the ranges as singular keys sharing the same value:

```py
NEW_TIERS = {k:v for tup,v in TIERS.items() for k in range(tup[0], tup[1]+1)}
```

And now your look-up function will be both more readable and much more efficient (and in fact even obsolete...):

```py
def range_index(table, val):
    return table.get(int(val))
```

The downside is ofcourse the memory over-head, but that is already for your consideration according to your resources.

Comment: I think it is not working for float values between whole numbers. For example: `2.5` will return `None`

Comment: ah, rounding. should be fine for my purposes. if dealing with smaller ranges, maybe not good but that can be for someone else's problem.